# How to add multiple ListTile in end drawer without scrolling in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to add multiple around (13 items) in end drawer in flutter without scrolling [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Expanded` widget as the parent of those item and place under `Column`.

Your Drawer should be like :

```
Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(), //Your Blue Section
      Expanded( // Item 1
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.00),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(),
              Text(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded( // Item 1
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.00),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(),
              Text(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded( // Item 2
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.00),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(),
              Text(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded( // Item 3
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.00),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(),
              Text(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded( // Item 4
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.00),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(),
              Text(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      .
      . and so on ...
      .
    ]      
  )
),
```

Comment: You're welcome. However, There are devices still in the market with small screens or lower resolution so you might not want the drawer items to look very compressed hence  you should consider making it scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

put the column that contain items inside overflow widget

```dart
OverflowBox(
  child : Column(
    children: [ 
         /// items 
      ]
   )
)
```